# And Entry and Edit Navigation Property using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is probably a duplicated question, but I cannot find the exact answer or documentation.

I have a two tables with one to many relationship. Each item has a category, and CategoryID is the foreign key.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add an item, it looks like I always need to make sure category is null. If I forgot to set it to null, EntityFrame will create a new category even the old catagory exist.

For example:
My db is:

```
Item
Item #1: id: 1, name TV categoryId : 1
Item #2: id: 2, name DVD categoryId : 1
Item #3: id: 3, name Cat categoryId: 2

Categories
Category #1: id: 1 name: electronics
Category #2: id: 2 name: pets.
```

If my code is

```
using (var dbContext = new DBContext())
{
    Category category = dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CategoryID = 2);
    Item item = new Item()
    {
        Name = "dog",
        CategoryId = 2,
        Category = category,
    };

    dbContext.Items.Add(item);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will cause another new category with duplicated name "pet" created. I guess it makes sense. But I want to know is there a guideline of how/when to set to the collection object(Category object) or when should I set it to null? What's SOP when I need to update an existing item's category? If I simply use the following code:

```
using (var dbContext = new DBContext())
{
    Item item = dbContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemID == 1);
    item.CategoryId = 2;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will not work. should I manually set the item.Category property to null? Or there is a better formation in EF6?

Answer (score 0):

change Item Class to this

```
public partial class Item
{
    public long ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey="CategoryID"]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

then you are using [ForeignKey] annotation in your class that connect id to data, and when you are creating new data just put category Id not data.

```
Item item = new Item()
{
    Name = "dog",
    CategoryID = 2,
};
```